# rowSums() to count number of both non-missing and unique values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, rowsum

Let's say I have this dataframe

```
> df
   mr_daterd mr_daterd_fu1 mr_daterd_fu2
1 2018-03-05    2018-03-05          <NA>
2 2019-05-04          <NA>    2020-03-05
3 2020-01-03    2020-06-06    2021-04-02
```

Each row represent a patient and the dates represent MRI scans. I want to count the number of MRI scans per row, i.e. `rowSums()` of non-missing values. However, some patient had several scans at the same date. Therefore, the `rowSums()` should only count unique non-missing values.

Eg, using

```
df_new <- df %>%
  mutate(
n_mri = rowSums(!is.na(select(., contains('mr_daterd'))))
)
```

Gives

```
> df_new
   mr_daterd mr_daterd_fu1 mr_daterd_fu2 n_mri
1 2018-03-05    2018-03-05          <NA>     2
2 2019-05-04          <NA>    2020-03-05     2
3 2020-01-03    2020-06-06    2021-04-02     3
```

The `n_mri` for **row 1** should be 1, and not 2, because `2018-03-05` is duplicated in `mr_daterd` and `mr_daterd_fu1`.

**Expected output**:

```
> df_new
   mr_daterd mr_daterd_fu1 mr_daterd_fu2 n_mri
1 2018-03-05    2018-03-05          <NA>     1
2 2019-05-04          <NA>    2020-03-05     2
3 2020-01-03    2020-06-06    2021-04-02     3
```

Data

```
df <- structure(list(mr_daterd = structure(c(17595, 18020, 18264), class = "Date"), 
    mr_daterd_fu1 = structure(c(17595, NA, 18419), class = "Date"), 
    mr_daterd_fu2 = structure(c(NA, 18326, 18719), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dplyr` solution using `n_distinct` and `c_across`.

```
df %>% 
  rowwise %>% 
  mutate(n_mri = n_distinct(
    c_across(contains('mr_daterd')), 
    na.rm=TRUE)) %>%
  ungroup()


# A tibble: 3 × 4
# Rowwise: 
  mr_daterd  mr_daterd_fu1 mr_daterd_fu2 n_mri
  <date>     <date>        <date>        <int>
1 2018-03-05 2018-03-05    NA                1
2 2019-05-04 NA            2020-03-05        2
3 2020-01-03 2020-06-06    2021-04-02        3
```

Comment: `length(unique(x))` is equivalent to `n_distinct(x)`

Comment: Thanks for the improvement! I get to learn something new too!

Answer (score 3):

With `base` R, you could use `apply()`:

```r
apply(df, 1, \(x) sum(!is.na(unique(x))))

# [1] 1 2 3
```

Comment: How can I integrate this into my `mutate`-pipe?

Comment: @cmirian something like `df %>% mutate(n_mri = apply(., 1, \(x) sum(!is.na(unique(x)))))`

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution, based on `purrr::pmap`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(n_mri = pmap_int(., ~ n_distinct(c(...), na.rm = T)))

#>    mr_daterd mr_daterd_fu1 mr_daterd_fu2 n_mri
#> 1 2018-03-05    2018-03-05          <NA>     1
#> 2 2019-05-04          <NA>    2020-03-05     2
#> 3 2020-01-03    2020-06-06    2021-04-02     3
```

Comment: It should be `pmap_int()`, otherwise `n_mri` will be a list-column.

Comment: Thanks, @DarrenTsai, for having commented my solution! Could you please tell me what is the difference, in practice, to have a list-column or a vector of integers?

Comment: Got it now, @DarrenTsai! That is something very subtle: for instance, if we try to subtract a number to a list-column of integers, we get `numeric(0)`, while without a list-column, we get the correct values. Thanks a lot for having called my attention to that!

Answer (score 0):

An option with `collapse`

```
library(collapse)
dapply(df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = fndistinct)
[1] 1 2 3
```